# Joomla! 3.8.5 Adminpanel Template Edit Not Showing 'Advanced' Tab

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla. Tried to create a new template using the Joomla official document.
https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

Successfully created the template and installed through Joomla Admin panel.
When I try to set Logo for my template, I can not find out **Advanced** tab, but it is showing for Joomla default template (protostar - Default).

Here I am attaching two screen shots of Default template and My Template.
[image: Default Joomla Template]

[image: Mytemplate]

Please guide me what to do to get **Advanced** tab for my template. Your valuable comments will save my time.

Answer (score 1):

You would define these details in your template's 'texmplateDetails.xml' file, then use them in your template's index.php file

If you inspect the templateDetails.xml file in the Protostar template you'll find the block below, you could use this as a starting point and add it to your templateDetails.xml file.

The second step in the process is taking values or elements defined in the template styles and integrating them with your actual template.

Again, if you inspect what's happening with Protostar it will probably be enough to get you started.  In Protostar > index.html you'll find

```
$logo = '<img src="' . JUri::root() . $this->params->get('logoFile') . '" alt="' . $sitename . '" />';
```

and

```
<?php echo $logo; ?>
```

This pulls in the value for the logo file specified in the template styles and adds it to the frontend view of the site.

Portion of templateDetails.xml from Protostar

```
<config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="advanced">
                <field 
                    name="templateColor" 
                    type="color" 
                    label="TPL_PROTOSTAR_COLOR_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_PROTOSTAR_COLOR_DESC" 
                    class="" 
                    default="#08C"
                />

                <field 
                    name="templateBackgroundColor" 
                    type="color" 
                    label="TPL_PROTOSTAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_PROTOSTAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR_DESC" 
                    class="" 
                    default="#F4F6F7"
                />

                <field 
                    name="logoFile" 
                    type="media" 
                    label="TPL_PROTOSTAR_LOGO_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_PROTOSTAR_LOGO_DESC" 
                    class="" 
                    default=""
                />

                <field 
                    name="sitetitle"  
                    type="text" 
                    label="JGLOBAL_TITLE"
                    description="JFIELD_ALT_PAGE_TITLE_LABEL"
                    default=""
                    filter="string" 
                />

                <field 
                    name="sitedescription"  
                    type="text" 
                    label="JGLOBAL_DESCRIPTION"
                    description="JGLOBAL_SUBHEADING_DESC"
                    default=""
                    filter="string" 
                />

                <field 
                    name="googleFont"
                    type="radio"
                    label="TPL_PROTOSTAR_FONT_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_PROTOSTAR_FONT_DESC"
                    class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
                    default="1"
                    >
                    <option value="1">JYES</option>
                    <option value="0">JNO</option>
                </field>

                <field 
                    name="googleFontName" 
                    type="text" 
                    label="TPL_PROTOSTAR_FONT_NAME_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_PROTOSTAR_FONT_NAME_DESC" 
                    class="" 
                    default="Open+Sans"
                    showon="googleFont:1" 
                />

                <field 
                    name="fluidContainer"
                    type="radio"
                    label="TPL_PROTOSTAR_FLUID_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_PROTOSTAR_FLUID_DESC"
                    class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
                    default="0"
                    >
                    <option value="1">TPL_PROTOSTAR_FLUID</option>
                    <option value="0">TPL_PROTOSTAR_STATIC</option>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
```

A reminder though that for elements which wouldn't typically change much, there's nothing to stop you from using a simpler approach of adding them directly to your template's index.php file, eg

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/images/myimage.png" alt="Custom image" class="customImage" />
```

Good luck!